# How to set a static block in magento for individual sites

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

in the magento [wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-create-and-edit-static-blocks) for adding static blocks, there is an option to select the store views for that static block. But in magento 1.5.0.1 i don't find this option. How do i set a store view for a static block? I want to add cms pages like Terms & Conditions where each store would have its own terms & conditions page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you *should* have the option to select store views that the static block is valid for when creating/editing it **unless** you are in single store mode.

So, the answer is you just follow the directions from the [wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-create-and-edit-static-blocks) page **if** you are in multi-store mode.

Comment: Thanks. Dint realise that store views option would only show up on a multi-store setup. I have a multi store setup on my server but not locally, so failed to notice this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple static blocks, one for each store, and then have them applied to different cms pages. The cms pages can then be different per store.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really simple way of creating & displaying static blocks on a per site basis.

Requirement - you want different messages displayed on the 404 error page on a store by store basis.

Implementation -

1. Create a separate 404 static block for each store (as Lee suggested above)
2. Add each static block into the 404 CMS page
3. Magento will only display the appropriate static block for each store

This is the case with Magento CE 1.7.02 & probably later/earlier versions too